# Regex string after plus symbol

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Match string after "+" symbol and separated by space:

```
import re
s = '(A) 2011-03-02 2011-03-01 Call Mom +project1 +project2'
re.findall('\s(\+.*?)', s)
# result ['+', '+']
re.findall('\s(\+project[0-9]*)', s2)
# result ['+project1', '+project2']
```

My target match parts are `+project1` and `+project2`. Why this pattern `re.findall('\s(\+.*?)', s)` can not find these targets?

Comment: `.*?` is non greedy and there is no anchor or boundary following.

Comment: I think the possible reason could be that `?` is for 0 or 1 char and `*` is for 0 to any number. I think the regex is confusing. Try removing `?`

Comment: @Bharat23 If you remove the `?` then `.*` will match 0+ characters except a newline and will match from the first `+` until the end of the string which will overmatch.

Comment: @Bharat23 `?` after `*` is non greedy. Remove `?` will match `'+project1 +project2'`, it's not my target part.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried to add a boundadry `"\s(\+.*?)\s"`, matching part is `['+project1']`. I can't get `[+project2]`

Comment: That will only match the first one as there is no `\s` for the second part to match. If you want to use the non greedy version and the values have to be separated by a space, then you could use a lookahead `\s(\+.*?)(?=\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/LIoxGu/1 But if you don't want to match spaces, you could also match `\+\S+`

Comment: @l0o0 because there's no space character after `+project2`, try this and see `\s\+.*?(?=\s|$)`, but the simplest one you should use here is `\+[^\s]+`

Comment: @CodeManiac oh yes, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `\w` (the word character) here in conjunction with a `+` sign (for one or more of the aforementioned) instead of `*?`.

The resulting regex would be: `\s(\+\w+)`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/kJuZJc/1